# Az acr commands in powershell is not working

Tags: azure, powershell, command-line-interface

I am not able to run '`

> az acr

`' commands.
Getting below error.
[image]

I tried to uninstall and re-install the Azure CLI msi. But no luck.
Installer version: azure-cli-2.21.0.msi

How can I get the command to run?

p.s: I can see `az --help` and some other commands works.

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/16361 It looks like an open issue...damn!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for some reason, My profile got updated and that lead to not listing of the subgroups when I did `az --help`. Pointed it to `latest` and I could see all the sub groups including acr.

```
az cloud list-profiles --show-all
az cloud set --name AzureCloud --profile  latest
```